# Adding Data from Beautiful Soup table to a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I'm a beginner to python and programming in general, and I was wondering how I would make the outputted data a list. I used bs to extract data from a table and attempt to make a list with the data, but I end up only adding the first number to the list. Can someone provide me assistance and an explaination?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession 

s = HTMLSession()


url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/ext'

def get_data(url):
  r = s.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  return soup


with open('document.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write(str(get_data(url)))
  
with open('document.txt', 'r') as html_file:
  contents = html_file.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml') 
forecast_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'zebra tb-wt fw va-m tb-hover')

wtitle = soup.title.text
print(wtitle)


print("------")

def get_weather_high(forecast_table):
  print("Weather Highs:")
  for high in forecast_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows1 = high.find_all('tr')
    for row1 in rows1:
      pl_high = row1.find_all('td')
      pl_high = [td.text.strip() for td in pl_high]
      pl_high = pl_high[1:2]

      for pl_high_final in pl_high:
        pl_high_final = pl_high_final[0:3]
        print(pl_high_final)

get_weather_high(forecast_table)
```

[This the output. Instead of each line being a number, I want to have it all under on list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eXDr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list before your for loop and just append your data instead of printing it and then just print the list after the for loop

```py
data = []
def get_weather_high(forecast_table):
  print("Weather Highs:")
  for high in forecast_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows1 = high.find_all('tr')
    for row1 in rows1:
      pl_high = row1.find_all('td')
      pl_high = [td.text.strip() for td in pl_high]
      pl_high = pl_high[1:2]

      for pl_high_final in pl_high:
        pl_high_final = pl_high_final[0:3]
        data.append(pl_high_final)

  print(data) # or return data if you need it some where else
```